# Show Selected Items in SplitApp

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to UI5. Can somebody help me to show selected tabs in [SplitApp](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/preview)? I wan't to do [something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators_animate) in UI5.

Comment: What do you mean by "tabs"? And show them where? What have to tried to achieve that? What documentation parts did you read? Please, specify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example page and switch to "Single Selection (Master)" in the dropdown.

[Example List - Selection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelection/preview)

You'll have to add `mode="SingleSelectMaster"` to the list. Now the selected item will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but i'm using 'SplitApp'. Mode is not an attribute of splitApp.`https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/preview` in this check for `Master 2` page. child tags i want to show selected